# Repository config file issue with Egit and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am getting a "Multiple problems have occurred" error window in eclipse and the following is the more detail I get:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>
> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   Repository config file V:\git\broadband_production.git\config invalid Cannot read file V:\git\broadband_production.git\config

I can access the same git data using a git bash, but I would like to be able to continue using the EGit funcionality in eclipse.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: which version of egit are you using? and on what git operation does the error come?

Answer (score 2):

Does your config file have a [UTF-8 byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? If it does, you'll have to upgrade to the nightly version of EGit, which includes the recent [fix for handling UTF-8 BOM](https://git.eclipse.org/r/7830).

Use the following update site to upgrade: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly